# How to dynamically visualize dataset on web?

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, data-visualization

I am developing a website where I have around 800 data sets. I want to visualize my data using bar charts and pie charts, but I don't want to hard code this for every data set. What technology can I use to dynamically read the data from a json/csv/xml and render the graph? (btw I'm going to use a Python based backend (either Django or Flask))

Answer (score 0):

Js library like d3.js or highcharts can be helpful to solve your problem. You can easily send the data from sever to front-end where these library can gracefully plot the data.